# Primitive element of a field extension

Tags: nt.number-theory

Hi,
I want to determine a primitive element for root expressions of the extension $\mathbb{Q}\left( m^{\frac{1}{a}}, n^{\frac{1}{b}} \right)$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Question 1: In the case $m$ and $n$ are coprime and squarefree, I think that the degree of field extension is $ab$. It is right?

Question 2: I want to determine a primitive element. My assumption is, that tt's always the element $m^{\frac{1}{a}}+n^{\frac{1}{b}}$.

For that I would have to show that $\frac{m^{\frac{1}{a}}}{n^{\frac{1}{b}}}\frac{\zeta_{a}^{i}-\zeta_{a}^{j}}{1-\zeta_{b}^{k}}$ is not 1 for $i, j \in \left\lbrace 0, \ldots, a-1\right\rbrace$, $k \in \left\lbrace 1, \ldots, a-1\right\rbrace$.

Thanks and best regards
Florian M.

Comment: You should change the tag to "number theory".

Comment: I retagged. (The problem is that "number theory" was in all likelihood intended. Yet this doesn't work as there must not be a space in a tag so it becomes 'number' and 'theory'.)

Comment: I think this question needs a precise definition of $\mathbf{Q}(m^{1/a},n^{1/b})$ before it is meaningful. The issues here are a little thornier than one might think at first.

Comment: I'm not sure about the degree, but at least it's not difficult to prove that $m^{1/a}+n^{1/b}$ is a primitive element. Namely, if an element of the Galois group fixes this sum then it has to fix both terms, as can be seen by looking at the real parts. (Strictly speaking this works when $m,n$ are positive, are you assuming this ?)

Comment: (So the assumptions "m,n coprime and squarefree" are not needed for Question 2)

Comment: @François: How follow that it must be the identity?
Thansks!

Comment: @Florian: Let $L$ be the Galois closure of $\mathbf{Q}(m^{1/a},n^{1/b})$ and $\sigma \in \mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbf{Q})$ fixing $m^{1/a}+n^{1/b}$. Since $\sigma(m^{1/a})$ is conjugate to $m^{1/a}$ we must have $\sigma(m^{1/a})=\zeta \cdot m^{1/a}$ for some $a$-th root of unity $\zeta$, and similarly $\sigma(n^{1/b})=\zeta' \cdot n^{1/b}$. Now we have $\zeta \cdot m^{1/a}+\zeta' \cdot n^{1/b}=m^{1/a}+n^{1/b}$ and looking at the real parts we get $\zeta=\zeta'=1$ so $\sigma$ fixes both $m^{1/a}$ and $n^{1/b}$. This shows $\mathbf{Q}(m^{1/a},n^{1/b})=\mathbf{Q}(m^{1/a}+n^{1/b})$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to Q1 is yes, here is a somewhat pedestrian proof.

I'll assume $m,n \geq 2$ are coprime and squarefree, and that $m^{1/a}$ (resp. $n^{1/b}$) denotes the unique real $a$-th root of $m$ (resp. real $b$-th root of $n$).

Recall that $K=\mathbf{Q}(n^{1/b})$ has degree $b$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ (use Eisenstein's criterion). Let us prove directly that $X^a-m$ is irreducible over $K$. Over $\mathbf{C}$ we have

\begin{equation*}
X^a-m = \prod_{k=0}^{a-1} X-\zeta_a^k m^{1/a}
\end{equation*}
If $P$ is a nontrivial factor of $X^a-m$ over $K$, of degree $1 \leq d \leq a-1$, then the constant term of $P$ is of the form $\zeta \cdot m^{d/a}$ for some root of unity $\zeta$. Since $K \subset \mathbf{R}$, we must have $\zeta=\pm 1$, so that $m^{d/a} \in K$. Since $d/a$ is not an integer, we deduce that there must exist a prime $p$ (dividing $a$) such that $m^{1/p} \in K$. In particular $p$ divides $b$.

Now using the Galois correspondence, it is not too hard to show that the unique subfield of degree $p$ of $K$ is $\mathbf{Q}(n^{1/p})$. So we get $\mathbf{Q}(m^{1/p})=\mathbf{Q}(n^{1/p})$. It remains to compare the discriminants of these number fields to get a contradiction. The prime $p$ divides at most one of the numbers $m$ and $n$, say $p$ doesn't divide $m$. Then any prime divisor $q$ of $m$ ramifies in $\mathbf{Q}(m^{1/p})$ but not in $\mathbf{Q}(n^{1/p})$, whence a contradiction.

As noted in my comment, the answer to Q2 is always yes, and one doesn't need the assumption "$m,n$ coprime and squarefree" for that.

Comment: Hi,
but how do you use Galois correspondence? There is no Galois extension!?
Thanks and best greetings
Florian

Comment: @Florian : One uses the Galois correspondence for the Galois closure $L=\mathbf{Q}(n^{1/b},\zeta_b)$ of $K$. In fact the Galois correspondence is not needed here. Since $\mathbf{Q}(m^{1/p}) \subset \mathbf{Q}(n^{1/b})$ we have that $n^{1/b}$ has degree $b/p$ over $\mathbf{Q}(m^{1/p})$. Its minimal polynomial is a product of $b/p$ factors of the form $X-\n^{1/b} \zeta_b^{k}$ with $0 \leq k \leq b-1$. Looking at the constant term yields $\zeta \cdot n^{1/p} \in \mathbf{Q}(m^{1/p})$ with $\zeta =\pm 1$ like before so that $\mathbf{Q}(m^{1/p})=\mathbf{Q}(n^{1/p})$.